# Bind datatable with classes into a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatable, datagrid

I am trying to bind a datatable with classes into a datagrid.

The code behind where I have program the datatable and the classes is this one:

```
 public partial class MainWindow :  Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Property Changed stuff
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    private DataTable _dt;
    public DataTable dt
    {
        get { return _dt; }
        set
        {
            _dt = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("dt");
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext= this;


        // Create datatable
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        // Add columns (could be other ones)
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Standard", typeof(std)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Stat1", typeof(statObj)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Stat2", typeof(statObj)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Stat3", typeof(statObj)));

        // Add some example data
        std _std = new std { Name = "Objeto1", Id = "1", Picture = "C:\\temp\\Raccoon\\Std\\Objects\\Atmo1ManageDialogAddon\\V1.0\\Common\\Picture.png", Version = "1.0.3.2" };
        statObj _stat1 = new statObj { Name = "Objeto1", Id = "1", Version = "1.0.3.2" };
        statObj _stat2 = new statObj { Name = "Objeto1", Id = "1", Version = "1.0.2.2" };
        statObj _stat3 = new statObj { Name = "Objeto1", Id = "1", Version = "1.0.1.2" };

        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row[0] = _std;
        row[1] = _stat1;
        row[2] = _stat2;
        row[3] = _stat3;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);

        row = dt.NewRow();
        row[0] = _std;
        row[1] = _stat1;
        row[2] = _stat2;
        row[3] = _stat3;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);

        row = dt.NewRow();
        row[0] = _std;
        row[1] = _stat1;
        row[2] = _stat2;
        row[3] = _stat3;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);

        // Set data context
        dtGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
        dtGrid.DataContext = dt;
    }


    public class std
    {
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Picture { get; set; }
        public string? Version { get; set; }
        public string? Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class statObj
    {
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Version { get; set; }
        public string? Id { get; set; }
    }

}}
```

This is my xaml (removing all the tests that I have done:

```
<Window x:Class="Raccoon.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Raccoon"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dtGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsReadOnly="True">
       
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Anybody know how to:

1. Create a DataGridCell template that should uses:

- For the first column bind an image and the name in a TextBlock. This column should uses the class std.
- For the rest of columns bind only the version. These columns should use the class statObj.

2. Be able to add all the neccesary columns in the code behind.

Now this is what the DataGrid shows:

[image]

Comment: Each question is supposed to be one question rather than a list.  Don't add columns in code behind if you can possibly avoid doing so. The recommended approach is xamlreader.parse or .load from xaml as a string if you must.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Answer (score 1):

When you have classes it's quite better to use a ObservableCollection which can then be bound to the DataGrid, doing so you will save much time since the Binding inside a DataTemplate will recognise the class and suggest it's fields. When using a collection you will not have to create the whole grid and columns structure, just a list with N istances of the same class and then the DataGrid will do it's job.

Then you can create the wpf DataGrid structure as you wish

You could set the DataContext property so you don't have to set the ItemsSource of the grid from code but that's not relevant.

Also I would suggest you to use a specific class (a model) just for all the bindings and interaction with the user control that can be separated from the main window class

Comment: Thanks for your comments and suggestions. I will do these modifications.